# PDFBox returns missing descendant font dictionary

Tags: java, pdfbox

when extracting the first page of a PDF I get `java.io.IOException: Missing descendant font dictionary`.
The extraction code is the following:

```
        PDDocument pdDocument = PDDocument.load(file);
        PageExtractor pageExtractor = new PageExtractor(pdDocument, 1, 1);
        PDDocument singlePageDocument = pageExtractor.extract();
```

It only happens with few PDFs and the error points to the Fonts definitions, but I am unclear on how fonts in PDF are processed by Apache PDFBox (using version v2.0.18).

Any tip?

Thanks

Comment: *"Missing descendant font dictionary"* indicates that your PDF contains composite fonts without components which is invalid. Please share the PDF in question for analysis, but if the indication above is true, it simply is broken.

Comment: Yes, v2.0.18, updated the question, tnx for pointing it out

Comment: You still did not share the PDF for analysis.

Comment: Unable to share it at the moment, will get back to you all

Comment: 2.0.19 has been released :-)