# Missing descendant font dictionary

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

Starting with an apology if I am breaking some process here.

I am aware that there is a question with exactly the same problem
[PDFBox returns missing descendant font dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60317866/pdfbox-returns-missing-descendant-font-dictionary) but the thread ends abruptly because the author wasn't able to give the details, unfortunately. Also due to low reputation wasn't able to continue that thread.

And it very well states the problem of missing composite font. I wanted to know if there is some way to fix it since the PDF opens fine in our browser but we are not able to deal with it programmatically.

Tried it on some variety of versions including the latest 2.0.21

I will share the PDF

Looking forward to you
@mkl, @Tilman Hausherr

Please let me know if you need more details.

My code trying to convert the PDF to images

```
       PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(pdfPath+"//"+fileName));
       PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(document);
       for (int page = 0; page < document.getNumberOfPages(); ++page) {
           BufferedImage bim = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(page, 300, ImageType.RGB);
           }
```

Comment: Adobe Acrobat Reader shows error messages when opening the document. iText RUPS reports cross reference issues. First impression, therefore: That PDF is broken. Different PDF viewers might not message this (PDF viewers are notoriously silent in such regards) but this doesn't mean that the file is valid. I'll look at it some more but if I were you I would reject such files, processing broken files is very error prone.

Comment: Thanks @mkl for all the support, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having downloaded the file when the link was available, I analyzed it.

Adobe Acrobat Reader shows error messages when opening the document. iText RUPS reports cross reference issues. First impression, therefore: That PDF is broken.

Nonetheless I looked closer but the result of that closer look was not better...

According to the cross references and trailers the PDF should contain 58 indirect objects with IDs 1 through 58. It turned out, though, that objects 32 through 49 are missing albeit most of them are referenced, some as descendant fonts. This explains why PDFBox reports missing descendant fonts.

Furthermore, objects 50 through 57 and 1 through 10 are not at the locations they should be according to the cross reference tables. Also the second cross reference table is at a wrong location and the file length is incorrect according to the linearization dictionary.

The way this is broken leaves the impression that the file is a mix of two slightly different versions of the same file; as if a download of the file was attempted but interrupted at some point and continued from a new version of the file; or as if some PDF processor somehow changed the file and tried to save the changed copy into the same file but was interrupted.

Summarized: The PDF is utterly broken.

If a PDF processor tries to repair it, you cannot be sure information from which version of the file you'll get, different PDF processors (if they can somehow make sense of it) are likely to interpret the file differently.

If possible, you should reject the file and request a non-broken version of it.

If not possible, copy the data from a viewer that appears to best repair it, manually check the copy for accuracy, and then check the whole extracted data for plausibility in regard to other information you have on the accounts in question. A little prayer won't hurt either.